# If $~(c - b) ^ 2 + 3cb = a^3~$ has nonzero integer solutions, then $~(a,c) \gt 1~$ or $~(b,c) \gt 1$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

If $~(c - b) ^ 2 + 3cb = a^3~$ has nonzero integer solutions, then $~(a,c) \gt 1~$ or  $~(b,c) \gt 1$?
I think this is true, how to prove this?

Comment: maybe you could give a motivation for this question, which I guess is related to your previous  one http://mathoverflow.net/questions/177429

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/885181/how-to-prove-c-b-2-3cb-x3-has-no-nonzero-integer-solutions/885372#885372.

Answer (score 5):

It is not true. Let us call an integer nice if its prime divisors are congruent to $1$ modulo $3$. If $n$ is nice, then in the ring of [Eisenstein integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer) it factors as $n=(c-b\omega)(c-b\bar\omega)$, where the factors $c-b\omega$ and $c-b\bar\omega$ are coprime. In particular, $(b,c)=1$ and we have $n=c^2+cb+b^2$. Note that $(b,c)=1$ implies that $n,b,c$ are pairwise coprime.

Now let $a$ be nice, then $n=a^3$ is also nice, hence by the above there exists a representation
$$a^3=c^2+cb+b^2=(c-b)^2+3cb$$
such that $a,b,c$ are pairwise coprime.

Here is a concrete counterexample: $a=7$, $b=-18$, $c=19$.

Comment: How about if $~c-b~$ is a cubic number?

Comment: @Mike: $c-b$ cannot be a cube (for distinct nonzero $b$ and $c$) because the Fermat equation $x^3+y^3=z^3$ has no nonzero solution (as proved by Euler).

Comment: If $n$ is nice, it has at least one such factorization with $c$ and $b$ coprime, (which is all you need for the answer) but if $n$ is not squarefree, then there are such (rational integer) factorizations with $c$ and $b$ not coprime (eg $7^{3} = 14^{2}+ (7 \times 14) +7^{2}).$

Comment: Why do you think so complicated? -- Already $a = 1$, $b = -1$, $c = 1$ is a counterexample!

Comment: @StefanKohl: You are right. At any rate, having more counterexamples is better. In fact my response gives all the counterexamples $a$ which are not divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in this thread showed how do the solutions of this equation.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/885181/how-to-prove-c-b-2-3cb-x3-has-no-nonzero-integer-solutions/885372#885372

Mutually simple solutions for one of these formulas are coming out.

$$x^2+xy+y^2=z^3$$

$$x=s^3+3ps^2-p^3$$

$$y=p^3+3p^2s-s^3$$

$$z=p^2+ps+s^2$$

If $p=2$ ; $s=3$  We get: $x=73$ ; $y=17$ ; $z=19$

The above example is not correct.

These decisions are determined by a formula.

$$x=s(p^2+ps+s^2)$$

$$y=p(p^2+ps+s^2)$$

$$z=p^2+ps+s^2$$

If $p=19$ ; $s=-18$ ; Then the solutions are. $x=-18(7^3)$ ; $y=19(7^3)$ ; $z=7^3$

That is equivalent to the solution. $x=-18$ ; $y=19$ ; $z=7$